# Primitive root of unity of irreducible factor of cyclotomic polynomial over finite field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

Sorry if the title is not descriptive, I couldn't find a way to properly describe the problem.

In the proof of the AKS algorithm ([link](https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/manindra/algebra/primality_v6.pdf)), the following is stated in Lemma 4.7:

"First note that since $h(X)$ is a factor of the cyclotomic polynomial $Q_r(X)$, $X$ is a primitive $r^{\text{th}}$ of unity in $F$."

I do not understand why $X$ is a *primitive* $r^{\text{th}}$ of unity in $F$. I can see that it is a root of unity in $F$, as $H(X)$ is a factor of $Q_r(X)$, which is in turn a factor of $X^r-1$. Hence $X^r \equiv 1 \pmod{p,H(X)}$. However, it is not clear to me why $X^k\not\equiv 1\pmod{p,H(X)}$ for all $0< k < r$.

Similar to the original AKS paper, Granville ([link](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2005-42-01/S0273-0979-04-01037-7/S0273-0979-04-01037-7.pdf)) states on the bottom of page 17 that

"(...), $\mathbb{F}$ contains $x$, an element of order $r$"

and on page 19, in the proof of Lemma 4.3:

"It can be shown that $x$ has order $r$ in $\mathbb{F}$ (...)"

Some background on notation:

- $p$ is a prime. $r$ is an integer less than $p$.
- $F$ and $\mathbb{F}$ refer to the finite field $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[X]/(h(X))$, where $h(X)\in (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[X]$ is an irreducible factor of the cyclotomic polynomial $Q_r(X)$.
- Granville uses lower capital '$x$' to denote the indeterminate in the polynomial ring.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: By definition, the roots of the cyclotomic polynomial $Q_r$ are exactly the $r$-th primitive roots of unity. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial

Comment: If $p$ is a prime, and $\gcd(r,p)=1$ then the roots of $Q_r(x)$ are still roots of unity of order $r$. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2727378/11619) (the argument there became a bit kludgy - I have touched the theme many times in various guises, and that just seems to be the closest match). Observe that the gcd assumption is crucial. If $F$ is a field of characteristic $p$, it can never have roots of unity of order $p$, hence multiples of $p$ are also excluded.

Comment: [A summary](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2024076/11619). Not sure it settles your questions. Feel free to comment.