# Is it true that he polynomial $\frac{x^p- 1}{x-1}$ ($p$ is prime) is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ iff $p$ is prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

> Is it true that the polynomial  $\frac{x^p- 1}{x-1}$ ($p$ is prime)  is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ iff $p$ is prime?

I know it will be true in $\mathbb Q[x]$. Can anyone please help me to understand  what happens in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$?

Comment: Are you sure that "($p$ is prime)" is supposed to be there? Should it, perhaps, be "($p$ is a natural number)"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial

Comment: Is the statement true for any natural number?@Arthur

Comment: This is false when $p=7$. For prime $p> 2$, it is true if and only if $2$ is a generator mod $p$.

Comment: "2 is a generator mod p" - means?@KCd

Comment: It is never irreducible when $p$ is not a prime (characteristic zero factors survive reduction modulo two). Over $\Bbb{F}_2$ it is irreducible, as KCd said, if and only if $2$ is a primitive root modulo $p$. So it is irreducible for example, when $p=3,5,11,13,19$ and not irreducible when $p=7,17,23$.

Comment: [Artin's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots) suggests that we get irreducibility for roughly $40$ per cent of the primes. Observe that $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ whenever $p\equiv\pm1\pmod8$. In those case the polynomial will automatically be reducible. This already proves that the polynomial is irreducible for at most one half of the primes.

Comment: primitive root modulo p means?@JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: An integer $a$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ if $n=p-1$ is the smallest positive integer such that $a^n\equiv1\pmod p$. In other words, here we want the order of $2$ in the group $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$ to be $p-1$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/305111/11619) for a bit more.

Comment: Yet in other words, $2^0,2^1,2^2,\ldots,2^{p-2}$ are all pairwise noncongruent modulo $p$.