# How to show that it is irreducible?

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $\gcd(p,n)=1$.
Consider $\;x^n-1$ over $\Bbb F_p[x]\;$. If its splitting field is $K$ find $\;[K:\Bbb F_p]$.

Now $K=\Bbb F_p(e^{2\pi i/n})$
Also the polynomial of which $e^{2\pi i/n}$ is a root is $1+x+x^2+\ldots +x^{n-1}$

But How to show that it is irreducible?

Do we need to use the fact that $\gcd(p,n)=1$.

Can I get some help please?

Comment: @DietrichBurde;$\Bbb Z_p$ means the ring $\Bbb Z_n$ where $n=p$ and it is a field

Comment: This finite field is usually denoted by $\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde;i meant that only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Irreducible cyclotomic polynomial over a field $\mathbb{F}_q$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305111/irreducible-cyclotomic-polynomial)

Comment: You can use $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for the cyclic group but in Galois field theory $\mathbb{Z}_p$ always refers to the $p$-adic integers (it is not a field but your question still made sense there)

Comment: @reuns,i don't understand why the assumption $\gcd(p,n)=1$ is needed?

Comment: @reuns,how is that useful in order to show it for the case here

Comment: Say $n=p$ odd. You know that $(a+b)^p = ?$ thus $x^p-1 = ?$. Trying to define what is the equivalent of $e^{2i \pi /n}$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ is what you are doing here. $\mathbb{Z}[e^{2i \pi /n}]/(p)$ contains $\mathbb{Z}/(p)=\mathbb{F}_p$ but it doesn't have to be a field.

Comment: @reuns,$n=kp\implies x^{kp}-1=(x^k)^p-1=(x^k-1)^p$

Comment: the polynomial $1+x+...+x^n $ is irreducible over $F_p$ iff p is of order $n-1$ $\pmod{n}.$ This is not always true. take $p=2$ and $n=15$ when that polynomial is divisble by both $x^2+x+1$ and $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1.$ If $n$ is itself a prime the iff condition is that $p$ is primitive (ie of order $n-1$) mod $n.$

Comment: @reuns;How do you know that $x^k-1$ splits in $\Bbb Z_p$