# Find the least prime $p$ such that $x^{22} + x^{21} + \cdots + x + 1$ irreducible over $F_p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

I unable to proceed. Anyone please help me. Problem from the book *Finite Fields and their applications* by Lidl and Niederreiter (#2.55 & #2.56).

1. Find the least prime $p$ such that $x^{22} + x^{21} + \cdots + x + 1$ irreducible over $F_p$.
2. Find then the  least primes $p$ such that $x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} + \cdots + x + 1$ irreducible over $\mathbb F_2$.

Comment: __Hint:__ Try for $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 = \frac{ x^ 5 - 1 } { x - 1 } $ first.

Comment: I have answered this (essentially) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/305123/11619) (among other places). In the first question you need $p$ to be a generator $\Bbb{Z}_{23}^*$. In the second question you need $2$ to be a generator of $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$. Searching for the answer is then straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting Theorem $2.47$ from same book (Finite Fields and their application by Lidl and Niederreiter)

> **Theorem:** The cyclotomic field $K^{(n)}$ is a simple algebraic extension of $K$ . Moreover:
>
> i. If $K = \mathbb{Q}$ , then the cyclotomic polynomial $Q_n$ is irreducible over $K$ and $[K^{(n)} : K] = \varphi(n)$ .
>
> ii. If $K = \mathbb{F}_q$ with $\gcd(q, n) = 1$ , then $Q_n$ factors into $\varphi(n)/d$ distinct monic irreducible polynomials in $K[x]$ of the same degree $d$ , $K^{(n)}$ is the splitting field of any such irreducible factor over $K$ , and $[K^{(n)} : K] = d$ , where $d$ is the least positive integer such that $q^d \equiv 1 \mod n$ .

So we have to find the least prime for which $22$ is the least integer  $d$ such that $23|(p^{d}-1)$. Thus, the answer is $5$.