# How to factor $x^5-1$ for binary codes

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, cyclic-groups

Currently, I have that I can do:

$$ x^5-1 = (x-1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1) $$

Then I thought I could do:

$$ x^5-1 = (x-1)(x(x+1)(x^2+1)+1) $$

However I want to use the factorization to find all cyclic codes in $[5, k]$. For that, I need to find all irreducible factors of $ x^5-1 $. I am not seeing if I can actually reduce $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ any further

Comment: Does this mean you are you factorising over $\mathbb Z_5$?

Comment: @LukeCollins not it is in $Z_2$

Comment: If you want to factor over the reals...$(x^5 - 1)=(x-1)(x^2 + \frac {1-\sqrt 5}{2}  x + 1)(x^2 + \frac {1-\sqrt 5}{2}  x + 1) = (x+\cos \pi)(x^2 + 2\cos\frac {2\pi}{5}  x + 1)(x^2 +2\cos\frac {4\pi}{5}  x + 1)\\$     Over the Compex numbers $(x - e^{2\pi i})(x - e^{\frac {2\pi}{5} i})(x - e^{\frac {4\pi}{5} i})(x - e^{\frac {6\pi}{5} i})(x - e^{\frac {8\pi}{5} i})$

Comment: @DougM this is over a galois field $GF_2$. So unfortunately, in this case I do not think that factorization is valid for this problem?

Comment: It ends here. $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $GF(2)$. Meaning that there are relatively few binary cyclic codes of length five. The repetition code, the overall parity code and the trivial codes :-)

Comment: A general result relevant here is that the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$, $n$ odd, is irreducible over $GF(2)$ if and only if $2$ generates the multiplicative residue class group $\Bbb{Z}_n^*$. Here $$\Bbb{Z}_5^*=\{2^0=1,2^1=2, 2^2=4, 2^3=3\}$$ so this holds. The proof uses Galois theory of finite fields. For example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/305123/11619).

Answer (score 1):

Over `GF(2)`$=\Bbb F_2$ we have $1=-1$ and $2=0$. The factorization (using prime factors in $\Bbb F_2[x]$) of the given polynomial is already
$$
x^5+1 =(x+1)(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)\ .
$$
To see that $f=(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$ is irreducible (= prime in $\Bbb F_2[x]$), it is enough to check there is no factor of degree one or two. The irreducible factors in degrees one and two are $x$, $(x+1)$, and $(x^2+x+1)$. The factors in degree one are easily excluded. (Since $f(0)=f(1)=1$.) And the rest by division with rest of $f$ by $(x^2+x+1)$ is $x+1$, so the factor in degree two is also excluded.

---

A computer algebra system is useful in such cases, for instance [sage](https://www.sagemath.org) delivers the factorization:

```
sage: R.<x> = PolynomialRing(GF(2))
sage: factor(x^5+1)
(x + 1) * (x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)

sage: # note that x^2 + 1 is reducible... 
sage: factor(x^2+1)
(x + 1)^2
```