# Constructing a field of order $2^6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

> Construct a finite field of order $2^6$.

My solution: We just need to find a degree six polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2$. The cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_7(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6$ is monic and irreducible. Hence the quotient $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/\langle \Phi_7(x)\rangle$ is a field containing $2^6$ elements. Moreover, the elements satisfy $a\alpha+b:\Phi_7(\alpha)=0$. Is this right?

Comment: What is your $a$ and $b$? If your $a,b$ are in $\Bbb{F}_2$, then your conclusion is wrong, since $\Bbb{F}_{16}$ is a $4$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{F}_2$.

Comment: You need to find an *irreducible* polynomial $\in \Bbb{F}_2[x]$ of degree $6$. No $\Phi_7$ doesn't work as its splits in $\Bbb{F}_8$.

Comment: @reuns:  I see the factorization in the answer below, but I'm wondering how you knew that $\Phi_7$ splits in $\mathbb F_8$ -- is there a general rule that you used?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner There is a rule, see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305111/irreducible-cyclotomic-polynomial?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 4):

> Is this right?

Nope.

$1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6=(1 + x + x^3) (1 + x^2 + x^3)$ so it is not irreducible over $F_2$. You'll need to find an actual irreducible. One which would work is $x^6 + x + 1$.

If you're up for the challenge of fully constructing it by finding a primitive element and working out the multiplication, it might be worthwhile. 64 is big enough for a nontrivial challenge, but not impossible.

Comment: This is the point, +1. If memory serves, $x^6+x+1$ is actually a primitive polynomial. Meaning that its roots have multiplicative order $2^6-1$.