# Does two primitive $n$th roots of unity have the same minimal polynomial over a finite field of characteristic $p>0$.

Tags: galois-theory, examples-counterexamples, finite-fields, problem-solving

I face problems whenever I am asked to work with fields of positive characteristic and roots of unity over those fields.I am stuck with a similar problem and looking for some help regarding this problem.The problem is as follows:

> If $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are primitive $n$ th roots of unity over a finite field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$ and $n\neq p$.Then is it true that $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ have the same minimal polynomial over $k$.

I want to know exactly why we need the field to be finite field.Can someone give me a detailed answer or explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question is "No!!", in general (follow the link below for a more precise answer).

Possibly the simplest conterexample is in the field $\Bbb{F}_5$, where both $2$ and $2^{-1}=3$ are primitive fourth roots of unity with minimal polynomials $x-2$ and $x-3$ respectively.

If you think that was a cheating example, and (like me) prefer characteristic two examples then the simplest examples reside in the field $\Bbb{F}_8$. Modulo two we have the polynomial factorization
$$
x^7-1=(x-1)(x^3+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1).
$$
Implying that the roots of both cubic factors are seventh roots of unity. Seven being a prime they are all automatically primitive.

---

Over $\Bbb{Q}$ the minimal polynomial of the roots of unity of order $n$ is the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$, and the game to be played is how that factors modulo $p$. There are no repeated factors when $\gcd(p,n)=1$, and the conclusion is that the primitive roots of unity share the same minimal polynomial over $\Bbb{F}_p$ if and only if $\Phi_n(x)$ remains irreducible after reduction modulo $p$.

But the cyclotomic polynomial is rarely irreducible over the prime field. I have touched its factorization under various guises more often than I care to admit. Start for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/305111/11619) and check out the list of linked questions.

---

However, all the primitive roots of a given order (in some extension of $\Bbb{F}_p$) do have minimal polynomials of the same degree. This is because a field extension generated by one primitive root necessarily contains all the others (in a sense that can be made more precise for example by requiring that we work inside a fixed algebraic closure). Hence the minimal polynomials share the degree with that of the said field extension.